# PingFederate - How to authenticate Salted MD5 Hash Password?

Tags: pingfederate

Can anyone point me to how PingFederate can authenticate accounts with salted MD5 hash passwords?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use case you're after isn't totally clear - but I'm going to assume you are acting as an Identity Provider (IdP) with PingFederate and you have accounts stored in some system / database that have their passwords MD5 hashed (with a salt).

Depending on the version of PingFederate being used you may need a custom IdP Adapter (pre-6.6) or a custom Password Credentials Validator (6.6 and up).  The PingFederate SDK has Javadocs that describe the API's required along with sample code.  Your custom adapter/PCV will be some Java code that looks up the user's account, MD5-salt-hashes the incoming password and compares that result with the stored account.  If it's a match, the custom code will return a status code that indicates so.

You will of course then need your SP connection(s) then configured to use this IdP Adapter / PCV (within the HTML or HTTP Basic auth adapter).

Comment: The UC is for PungFederate to act as an IdP - your answer was spot on. With regards to the SP why would it need an adapter? Or are you refering to if my question was with regards to PingFederate acting as the SP and hence the adapter requirement? Thanks - very helpful.

Comment: To add to Scott's answer: If you already have an application that is authenticating user's in this datasource containing the Salted MD5 Hashed Passwords, it is not required to also have PingFederate authenticate those same users. We have Integration Kits that could potentially leverage your existing application. - Ian

Comment: Thanks Ian.  And WRT the SP note... My comment was that the "SP connection" needs the IdP adapter associated with it.  This is PingFederate acting as IdP, and the SP partner configuration within it needs to associate the adapter.  It's just how the adapter is linked to a given partner.  The SP itself could be any SAML compliant product.